How to reproduce missing Specular functionality in Blender 4.2?
Some important shader functions to control special values were removed in Blender 4.2. The transmission roughness for example. There is no way to reproduce it. This is important, if you update old peojects or expand them by new client wishes. You have always move back to the old Blender version.
Another functions differ from older versions and can result in trouble. One of those functions is the "Specular" option in the Principled Shader. It got new but lost also some functionality.
Question: Do someone know how how to reproduce the Specularity behavior that is known in old blender versions? See my example in Blender 3.6.5. How to reproduce the samespecularity in a metalness shader in Blender 4.2?
Blender 4.2:

Blender 3.6.x. Basically the same values, but different result.


You are a bit late to the party, the Principled BSDF has already been re-worked for 4.0, it is not new in 4.2, but I do not have an answer for you. But I actually never tried to find an answer as for most of the time I did not need the Specular setting. But actually the Specular reflection should only work on dielectric (non-metallic) materials, but it did work on metallic in the old material and this was removed to make it more physically accurate.. If you set the Metallic value to 0, then the Specular value behaves the same in both versions. Metallic reflection ≠ specularity.

Take a look at this and see if it helps https://developer.blender.org/docs/release_notes/4.2/eevee_migration/#materials

@Emir The changes from old to new Eevee in 4.2 have nothing to do with the 4.0 reworked version of the Principled BSDF (which is not an Eevee-specific shader either).

By the way, the settings are not the same: the old Principled BSDF, had the Specular Tint which you could set from 0 to 1 as a percentage how much the reflection should be tinted by the base color. In your screenshot it is 1, so 100% the base color blue. In the new version you can set a Specular Tint color instead of a factor. By default it is white, like yours. But to get a comparison to the old version it should have the same blue as the base color. Still the result is not exactly the same, but as I said it was reworked to be more realistic in terms of energy conservation etc.

Thank you. I'm asking for a friend. There are a some situations, where the old settings have sence and are important. The problem is: If you are working professional you haven't always the time to support the actual development bacuse of client jobs. Myself I am in the same situation like you Gordon. I don't use the specular values or very rare.
